# Разбить последовательность на группы по 5 символов СИ

Tags: c, массивы

Длинна последовательности не более 100 символов. Считается, что последовательность считана вся, если уже прочитано 100 символов, или любое другое заданное заранее пользователем число элементов. Разбить последовательность на группы по 5 символов (в последней группе сколько останется) и выдать каждую последовательность в обратном порядке.

Тк мы только начали изучать си, то в интернете почти нет информации о том, как это сделать простейшими операторами вроде сканф. Я примерно представил алгоритм, но программа выдает некорректный ответ, может вы сообразите где ошибка

```
#include 
#include 
#include 
#include 
#define N 100

int main()
{
int i, n,a,b;
char C[N];
setlocale(0, "");
printf("Введите количество символов\n");
if (scanf("%d", &n) == 0)
{
printf("Введен символ\n");
getch();
return 0;
}
if (n > N || n <= 0)
{
printf("Недопустимое число элементов\n");
getch();
return 0;
}
fflush(stdin);
printf("Введите массив элементов\n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
scanf("%c", &C[i]);
}
printf("Вы ввели: \n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
printf("%c ", C[i]);
}
printf("\nЭлементы после сортировки \n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
if (i+4 <= n)
{
a = i+4;
for (a; a > i; a--)
{
printf("%c ", C[a]);
}

}
else
{
a = i;
for (n; n > a; n--)
{
printf("%c ", C[n]);
}
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Индекс **i** медленно прибавляете

```
printf("\nЭлементы после сортировки \n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
if (i+4 <= n)
```

надо добавлять индекс побыстрее и проверка конца неправильная

```
printf("\nЭлементы после сортировки \n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i+=5)
if (i+4 < n)
```

Не весь пяток выводите:

```
a = i+4;
for (a; a > i; a--)
```

надо все пять :

```
a = i+4;
for (/*a*/; a >= i; a--)
```

Последний пакет символов опять с неправильной индексации:

```
a = i;
for (n; n > a; n--)
```

уменьшать надо на единицу и печатать первый тоже:

```
a = i;
for (--n; n >= a; n--)
```

Comment: Вы супер! Но у меня есть пара вопросов, если вам не составит труда, поясните :
printf("\nЭлементы после сортировки \n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i+=5)
if (i+4 < n)
- почему так быстро прибавляем индекс?

for (/*a*/; a >= i; a--) - что значит /*a*/ - я совсем дуб, как вы заметили, на указатель не похоже.

a = i;
for (--n; n >= a; n--) - и почему индекс нужно уменьшать на еденицу , даже первый?

Comment: Цикл по **i** указывает на первый элемент пятёрки, внутри цикла ещё один цикл ( он занимается печатью пятёрки). А главный цикл всего-лишь предоставляет начала пятёрок : `0 , 5 , 10 , ...` /*a*/ - Это всего-лишь закомментированный код - он ничего не делает поэтому и удалил. Элементы массива C[0],C[1],...,C[n-1]. Количество n штук. Поэтому и печатаем с конца : C[n-1],...